# Piping child items

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script that grabs a file folder `$file` and all child items and pipes them over to. Here is my script:

```
foreach-object -process {if (!$_.PSIsContainer) {$_.Name; $_.Length -gt 1mb; " " }}
```

And this returns each child item with True's and False's depending on if they're greater than 1mb.

But what I'm trying to do is get them to return with their file size and name if they're greater than 1mb.

How do I get them to return this information?

Answer (score 2):

Separate your filter and selection of properties

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Downloads\ -file | ? {$_.Length -gt 1mb} | select name,length
```

Note that the `-File` switch parameter, which limits results to *files* rather than directories, requires PowerShell version 3 or higher. In version 2, stick with `-not $_.PSIsContainer` in the `Where-Object` (`?`) block.